# Why text color affects the line breaking algorithm?

Tags: color, line-breaking

I have the following snippet,

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\testtext}{補\sm{史記}的\zm{褚先生}名\sm{少孫}，%
是\zm{漢朝}\zm{元}\zm{成}間的一個博士。}

\begin{document}
\Huge

\newcommand{\sm}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\zm}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\testtext

\renewcommand{\sm}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\zm}[1]{#1}
\testtext
\end{document}
```

for the commands `\sm` and `\zm`, I just use the `\textcolor` to emphasis some texts, but it gives me a quite different result between the character `漢` and `朝`.

Can anybody explain why?

Result Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can fix this by using LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX. (And in LuaLaTeX you can also load `luacolor` to make sure that colors never change lnebreaking, but that isn't even needed here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why?

The way color is handled by the color command is that it puts  a colored `\vrule` with the require box dimensions of the enclosing material then it
typesets in a zero width box using `\rlap` and then the text is overwritten to provide the typeset box, with a background color.

If you do:

```
\renewcommand{\sm}[1]{\hbox to 0pt{}#1}
\renewcommand{\zm}[1]{\hbox to 0pt{}#1}
```

TeX will see the same type of situation and the output will be the same.

See `\color@block` in the color package.

LuaTeX writes the pdf directive for color directly rather than through a `\vrule` and does produce correct output in both cases.

Comment: I don't see how it is relevant for this question how background colors are implemented since the question is about normal (foreground) colors. These color commands do not insert any boxes. (They do insert specials which in this case is enough for the effect, but in other cases they act quite different.)